I'm having a server error while making a Groq API call in nextjs server
I'm making a chatbot and for that i wanted to use llama. i used groq to make a specific system prompt. but now im getting 500 server error. i dont know where im making a mistake im new to typescript and ai models. the code for the api routes is
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { streamText } from "ai";
import { createOpenAI } from '@ai-sdk/openai';

const groq = createOpenAI({
  baseURL: 'https://api.groq.com/openai/v1',
  apiKey: process.env.GROQ_API_KEY,
});

console.log('GROQ_API_KEY:', process.env.GROQ_API_KEY);

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const data = new Response(JSON.stringify({
    query: "world"
  }), {
    status: 200, // HTTP status code
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  
  console.log(await data.text()); // Logs the response body as a string
  
    const { text, prompt } = await req.json();
    
    if (!prompt) return new Response("Prompt is required", { status: 400 });

    const result = await streamText({
      model: groq("llama3-8b-8192"),
      system: "You are the AIC (Artificial Intelligence Club) Society chatbot, an AI assistant designed to provide information about the AIC Society at our university. Your primary role is to assist students with queries related to various non-tech events organized by the society, the structure and organization of the society, membership details, and eligibility criteria.\n\nGuidelines for Interaction:\nEvents Information:\n\nProvide detailed information about upcoming non-tech events, including dates, locations, themes, and how students can participate.\nOffer insights into past events, including summaries and highlights.\nSociety Structure:\n\nExplain the organizational structure of the AIC Society, including the roles of different members and the hierarchy.\nClarify the responsibilities of each role within the society.\nMembership Details:\n\nProvide information on how students can become members of the AIC Society.\nExplain the membership benefits, including opportunities for involvement in events and other society activities.\nSelection Time and Eligibility Criteria:\n\nDescribe the timeline and process for selecting new members or officers within the society.\nOutline the eligibility criteria for membership and selection, including any necessary qualifications or prerequisites.\nTone and Style:\nBe friendly and approachable, ensuring that your responses are clear and helpful.\nUse a conversational tone to make interactions engaging and easy to understand.\nAlways provide accurate and up-to-date information.\nExample Queries:\n\"Can you tell me about the next non-tech event organized by the AIC Society?\"\n\"How is the AIC Society structured?\"\n\"What are the criteria to become a member of the AIC Society?\"\n\"When is the next selection period for new members or officers?\"",
      prompt: `Prompt: ${prompt}\nText: ${text}`,
    });

    return new Response(result.toAIStream(), {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
      },
    });
    console.log(await result.text)
}

and this is how ui takes the response from the router
const {
    completion,
    input,
    isLoading,
    handleInputChange,
    handleSubmit,
    setInput,
  } = useCompletion({
    body: { text },
    onFinish: (prompt, completion) => setText(completion.trim()),
    onError: (error) => toast.error(error.message),
  });


you can refer these docs to understand the various status codes.
https://console.groq.com/docs/errors

A 500 error is a generic server-side error, especially when there is no additional information given. You'll need to add error handling to find out the source of the error in order to fix it. Unfortunately, this post isn't an answer, but a guide to give you some insight in finding the error.
First, add some error handling around your API call, something like this should work:
let result;
try {
    result = await streamText({
        model: groq("llama3-8b-8192"),
        system: "You are the AIC (Artificial Intelligence Club) Society chatbot...",
        prompt: `Prompt: ${prompt}\nText: ${text}`,
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while streaming text:', error);
    return new Response("Internal Server Error", { status: 500 });
}

Add some logging to see the response or error details as well:
console.log('API Call Result:', result);


Make sure the input to your API is being properly parsed. It looks like you are trying to send JSON but are also manually creating a Response object. Ensure that your POST request payload is correct.

Make sure the content returned from streamText() is valid and well-formed. This might be causing the 500 error if it's not handled properly.


I can better answer your question when you are able to hone in on the specifics of the error. Get back to me when you get more info and we can get this working for you
